# UnRegister Hotkey from Other Process in delphi

Tags: delphi

My Problem in Add Global Hotkey when the ShortCutkey is defined by other process.

e.g

in my delphi apps defind global key ShortCutkeys Ctrl+A and so Ctrl+A is Defind Global by Other process. when press ShortCutkey(Ctrl+A) then other process capture it and my app Can not capture ShortCutkey.

use this code to add global

```
  KeyID:= GlobalAddAtom('#SelectAll');
  RegisterHotKey(Handle, KeyID, MOD_CONTROL, Ord('A'));
```

Comment: You need to uninstall the other app

Comment: You cannot unregister someone else's global hotkey.  You don't know the HWND or the ID that the hotkey was registered for.  Keyboard shortcuts are simply too short and broad to be globally unique across all apps. There is going to be *some* amount of conflict at times, especially for something as common as `Ctrl-A`.

Comment: Now  how to do get process name use global keys comes conflict?

Comment: What other application is registering `CTRL+A` as a global hotkey?! That seems awfully badly behaved.  *You* probably shouldn't be trying to register it as a global hotkey either - almost every other application expects to be able to use that for `select all`.

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly described the way global hotkeys work. You cannot change that. All you can do is mitigate the problem for your customers.

The `RegisterHotKey` function fails when the key combination you attempt to register is already used by something else. Take advantage of that behavior. Offer a way for users to customize the key combinations in your program, and when the user makes a selection, attempt to register it. If registration fails, then report the failure and prompt the user to select something else instead.

Global hotkeys are a shared resource. You need to make your program cooperate with others.